# Mysqldump error on unique columns using extended charsets

Tags: character-encoding, unique, mysql, phpbb

I'm doing a backup replication of some phpBB forums from one server to another using mysqldump, using some basic options:

```
mysqldump -h[server] --create-options --add-drop-database -R -E -B [database]
```

At the time of doing there was an error like this:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 9322: Duplicate entry '?????' for key 'wrd_txt'
```

In phpBB forums that is an UNIQUE key on a table in which every word posted is registered and counted. The problem seems to be [this one](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=21407):

> When mysqldump dumps a DOUBLE value, it uses insufficient precision to
>   distinguish between some close values (and, presumably, insufficient
>   precision to recreate the exact values from the original database). If
>   the DOUBLE value is a primary key or part of a unique index, restoring
>   the database from this output fails with a duplicate key error.

It is been caused due to some posts on cirilic alphabet on our forums; mysqldump seems to be taking cirilic characters as a simple value and truncating them, so every character seems to be the same at using cirilic alphabet (character represented as ? in this case). That results in encountering repeated values for strings of the same size in an UNIQUE key column.

**Is there any way to perform a dump using double precision using other options or through other tool?? Or a way to avoid this problem on dump??**

Just for the record, since that cirilic words on table was only there due to spam, and we were only interested on latin characters, I got ride of them using this command (maybe it would be useful for anyone).

```
delete from [table] where NOT HEX([column]) REGEXP '^([0-C][0-9A-F])*$';
```

Thanks a lot in advance!